# exceeding vector does not cause seg fault

Tags: c++, vector, segmentation-fault

I am very puzzled at the result of this bit of code:

```
std::vector<int> v;
std::cout << (v.end() - v.begin()) << std::endl;
v.reserve(1);
std::cout << (v.end() - v.begin()) << std::endl;
v[9] = 0;
std::cout << (v.end() - v.begin()) << std::endl;
```

The output:

```
0
0
0
```

So... first of all... `end()` does not point to the end of the internal array but the last occupied cell... ok, that is why the result of the iterator subtraction is still `0` after `reserve(1)`. But, why is it still `0` after one cell has been filled. I expected `1` as the result, because `end()` should now return the iterator to the second internal array cell.
Furthermore, why on earth am I not getting a seg fault for accessing the tenth cell with `v[9] = 0`, while the vector is only 1 cell long?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`v[9] = 0;`, you're just accessing the vector out of bound, it's [UB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). It may crash in some cases, and may not. Nothing is guaranteed.

And `v[9] = 0;`, you don't add element at all. You need to use `push_back` or `resize`:

```
v.push_back(0); // now it has 1 element
v.resize(10);   // now it has 10 elements
```

*EDIT*

> why does v[index] not create an element?

Because [std::vector::operator[]](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_at) just doesn't do that.

> Returns a reference to the element at specified location pos. No bounds checking is performed. 
>   Unlike std::map::operator[], this operator never inserts a new element into the container.

So it's supposed that the vector has the sufficient elements for the subscript operator.

BTW: What do you suppose vector should do when you write `v[9] = 0`? Before set the 10th element to `0`, it has to push 10 elements first. And How to set their values? All `0`? So, it won't do it, the issue just depends on yourself.

Comment: thanks, but why does v[index] not create an element?

Comment: @lotolmencre Think of the fun to be had by requesting v[678]. The vector would have to make 0 through 677 first. What values go in those new elements?

Answer (score 4):

First of all, [`end()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/end) gives you an iterator to one beyond the last element in the vector. And if the vector is empty then [`begin()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/begin) can't return anything else than the same as `end()`.

Then when you call [`reserve()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve) you don't actually create any elements, you only reserve some memory so the vector don't have to reallocate when you do add elements.

Finally, when you do

```
v[9] = 0;
```

you are indexing the vector *out of bounds* which leads to *undefined behavior* as you write to memory you don't own. UB often leads to crashes, but it doesn't have too, it may *seem* to work when in reality it doesn't.

As a note on the last part, [the `[]` operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_at) doesn't have bounds-checking, which is why it will accept indexing out of bounds. If you want bounds-checking you should use [`at()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/at).

Comment: ah, ok, so the index-operator does not affect the iterators of vector then. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is a guess, but hopefully a helpful one.

You will only get a segfault when you attempt to access an address that has not been assigned to your process' memory space. When the OS gives memory to a program, it generally does so in 4KB increments. Because of this, you can access past the end of *some* arrays/vectors without triggering a segfault, but not others.

Comment: Additionally, I found out on Windows7 at least, that only the first 64KB are marked as a fault, so if you access 64KB+1, no seg fault.   I had an unfortunate issue where one of my state classes had a very large buffer in the beginning of it, with all the accessory state variables were after the buffer.   `(MyClass*)(NULL)->m_uVariableBeyond64KBOffset` wouldn't cause a fault.